# What's the difference between a Node and an Elem in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

These two seem very similar.  In the function I ran in the REPL below, they appear to be interchangeable for the return type.

```
scala> import scala.xml.{Elem, Node}
import scala.xml.{Elem, Node}

scala> def addChild(parent: Elem, child: Node): Node = {
     |     parent.copy(child = parent.child ++ child)
     |   }
addChild: (parent: scala.xml.Elem, child: scala.xml.Node)scala.xml.Node
```

However, I see that `Elem` has a `.child` property and Node does not.  Generally, what is the difference between Elem vs Node?

Comment: @jwvh - it compiles just fine. edited post for clarity.

Comment: I found this blog post on Scala XML to be useful - http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/working-with-scalas-xml-support.

Answer (score 3):

The [Node scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-xml/#scala.xml.Node) says:

> An abstract class representing XML with nodes of a labelled tree. This class contains an implementation of a subset of XPath for navigation.

The [Elem scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-xml/#scala.xml.Elem) says:

> The case class Elem extends the Node class, providing an immutable data object representing an XML element.

When using the embedded xml syntax in scala `Elem`s are produced because it's the only concrete implementation of `Node` that scala knows about.

You can't create an instance of a `Node` without implementing its abstract methods (`child` and `label`). `Elem` accomplishes this for you and provides an easy way to create `Node` via a standard API.

`Elem` also adds a handful of helper methods that are often useful. In methods that need to decide between accepting a `Node` or an `Elem` it depends on whether or not these extra features are needed inside the method. Accepting a `Node` leaves you in a more flexible state to accept any implementation of that class. Accepting an `Elem` might provide with you some extra helpers, but it limits you to accepting only `Elem` implementations of `Node`. Many of `Elem`'s methods return `Node` (or `NodeSeq`) so in general you'll want to accept the more general `Node` (or `NodeSeq`) rather than an `Elem`.

Beyond just this discussion, it's generally considered good practice to accept the least specific type possible (`Node`) as a parameter and return the most specific type possible (`Elem`):

```
def f(x: Node): Elem = ...
```

Specific use cases should still be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: there are several kinds of node in an XML tree: elements, text nodes, attribute nodes, comment nodes etc. So every element is a node, but not every node is an element.